# Vissual studio Accessibility

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Please I am a visually impaired programmer. I have decided to develop apps in c# and vbnet but the problem I am facing now is how I can use screen reader like jaws and nvda to  add controls to the form. I have read the Microsoft accessibility  article, they stated that i can use ctrl + up and down arrows to brows through the controls but is not working please can someone help me with this issue?